# Is addition of small numbers faster than addition of big ones?

Tags: performance, automated-tests, benchmarking

There has been an ongoing discussion of this in the c# chat. The original question was this:

> Is calculating e.g. (Int32) 5+5 faster then 1234723847+32489237 ?

My initial thought was that there would be optimizations at the binary level to ignore padding zeros, so smaller numbers would be quicker.

So, I tested it. If you're interested, here's the program. If not, just skip to the results.

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
Int64 c = 0;
long msDifferential = 0;     //
int reps = 10; //number of times to run the entire program
for (int j = 0; j < reps; j++)
{            
    sw.Start();  //                
    sw.Stop();   // Just in case there's any kind of overhead for the first Start()
    sw.Reset();  //

    sw.Start();  //One hundred million additions of "small" numbers
    for (Int64 i = 0, k = 1; i < 100000000; i++, k++)
    {   
        c = i + k;
    }
    sw.Stop();

    long tickssmall = sw.ElapsedTicks;       
    long mssmall = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    sw.Reset();

    sw.Start();  //One hundred million additions of "big" numbers
    for (Int64 i = 100000000000000000, k = 100000000000000001; i < 100000000100000000; i++, k++)
    {
        c = i + k;
    }
    sw.Stop();

    long ticksbig = sw.ElapsedTicks;
    long msbig = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    //total differentials for additions
    ticksDifferential += ticksbig - tickssmall;   
    msDifferential += msbig - mssmall;                
}

//average differentials per 100000000 additions
long averageDifferentialTicks = ticksDifferential / reps;
long averageDifferentialMs = msDifferential / reps;

//average differentials per addition
long unitAverageDifferentialTicks = averageDifferentialTicks / 100000000;
long unitAverageDifferentialMs = averageDifferentialMs / 100000000;

System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\phillip.schmidt\My Documents\AdditionTimer.txt", "Average Differential (Ticks): " + unitAverageDifferentialTicks.ToString() + ", ");
System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\phillip.schmidt\My Documents\AdditionTimer.txt", "Average Differential (Milliseconds): " + unitAverageDifferentialMs.ToString());
```

---

### Results

**Debug Mode**

- Average unit differential: 2.17 nanoseconds

**Release Mode (Optimizations Enabled)**

- Average unit differential: 0.001 nanoseconds

**Release Mode (Optimizations Disabled)**

- Average unit differential: 0.01 nanoseconds

So in debug mode, "big" numbers take about 2.17 nanoseconds longer to add together, per addition, than "small" ones. However, in release mode, the difference isn't nearly as significant.

---

### Questions

So I had a few follow-up questions:

1. Which mode is most accurate for my purposes? (Debug, Release, Release(no opt) )
2. Are my results accurate? If so, what is the cause for the differences in speed?
3. Why is there so much greater of a difference in debug mode?
4. Is there anything else that I should have taken into consideration?

Comment: Is this supposed to be language/architecture-agnostic?

Comment: @BoltClock oh, didn't think to put a language tag in there. But yes, to a certain extent. The original question was, but then I got curious and started testing it with optimizations, etc

Answer (score 2):

The effects of specific optimizations will depend on your compiler. You should have a look at the assembly code generated in each case and compare what CPU instructions were generated. At the level of CPU, there shouldn't be any difference in performance dependent on the values you add if the same instructions are generated. The CPU has a clock signal and simple arithmetic operations will take the same number of clock ticks regardless of whether the operand's bits are ones or zeros if the same instructions are executed on the same sized operands. Memory effects may impact performance, but here the data is small enough for this to probably not matter much. In the disassembly you could check if your variables end up in registers. If not, one could wonder if with just a few variables effects which play an important role with larger data (like cache hits/misses, physical memory accesses etc.) also matter here. They might, as your CPU is capable of billions of arithmetic operations per second but RAM is an external device which is much slower. Regardless, such effects would be random and not depend on whether the values you add are large or small. Same should go for pipeline stalls, instruction reordering etc. In a series of experiments, performed at different times, the average time should be the same within a margin of error (the difference you get in release mode certainly falls into this category).

One possibility I see where there could be a difference would be a compiler which handled 64-bit numbers not directly by 64-bit instructions but using multiple 32-bit instructions. In such a case, a smart compiler might notice that the values you use in some loop can never grow beyond the limit of 32 bit numbers and issue instructions working only on a single 32 bit value instead of on two 32-bit values making up the 64-bit value. A look at the disassembly could reveal if that is the case.

Comment: But then how come in debug there was such a big (lol) difference?